# Called a stored javascript function from Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have created a stored javascript function in my MongoDB instance that counts the number of records in each collection.  If I go to my mongo shell and type:

```
> db.eval("getTotals()");
```

it works as expected.  if I try to call it through mongo like so:

```
totals = mongoose.connection.db.eval("getTotals()");
console.log(totals);
```

`undefined` gets logged.  Does anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: it's not a good idea to use JS function in the server, they are the least performant way to do anything.  Regular queries are always going to be faster and will have the advantage of not blocking other threads.

Comment: Why does mongo provide a way to do it then? Can you provide something that backs that up?

Comment: To provide a little context: getTotals() gets the document counts from 5 different collections. I had assumed calling one function on the server would be more performant than executing 5 different queries from mongoose. Why would the latter be faster?

Comment: @AbeMiessler: there are warnings on performance considerations of JavaScript queries [`eval()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/eval/) and [`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) in the MongoDB manual. If you can express your query using the standard MongoDB query operators, they will take advantage of indexes and enable much better concurrency. For your specific case of counts, there are further server-side optimisations in MongoDB 2.4+. JavaScript queries have greater flexibility at the expense of a performance/concurrency penalty.

Comment: @AbeMiessler why assume? Why not try it out?  Don't forget that while the db.eval() is running, nothing else can be running where the five client queries can share read lock with other read queries, plus they will use indexes.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky I would like to have an auto increment field and the following article hints as to how: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/ but since I don't have thousands of people typing the data into the database using the mongodb console I guess the function needs to be saved somewhere and called somewhere somehow. Is using db.eval the only option here or are there any other options. A nudge in the right direction would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most mongoose calls do not return in-line like this, but rather expect a callback to be passed in to process the results.

Completely untested, but you probably want something like:

```
mongoose.connection.db.eval("getTotals()", function(err, retVal) {
   console.log(retVal)
});
```

And in the real world, assign your result to a `var` outside of that scope or whatever you want to do.

Comment: I found documentation for evaluation here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.eval/ but there was no mention of a callback. Am I just looking in the wrong spot?

Comment: @abe that's  the mongo shell. This is mongoose isn't it? Mongoose functions implement callbacks. Did you try. I'm on mobile so can't test.Or type properly for that matter.