# Create atomic stored procedure / "stored JS" with MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

We need to create an atomic routine in our MongoDB database.

We need to iterate through a collection, find the highest number given a field from all documents in the collection, then increment it. We are working with some legacy data that we need to integrate, otherwise we'd have some atomic sequence already in place.

How can I create stored JS or a stored procedure in MongoDB that can run a whole routine atomically?

I am seeing some information but nothing is looking particularly clear to me:

[Called a stored javascript function from Mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21768588/called-a-stored-javascript-function-from-mongoose)

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongoose-orm/sPN3wfDstX4

https://github.com/mongoosejs/mongoose-function

Where can I find good information how to actually write an atomic/blocking stored procedure that runs in MongoDB, and how to actually invoke the stored procedure from the application?

Comment: There's no such thing as atomic/blocking stored procedure in mongodb. What you want to do _may_ be possible with `findAndModify`, but that's a) really hard to tell, given how vague your description is and b) is atomic only at document level.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev it's not a vague question at all, I described exactly what I want to do :) Well, what I want to do more exactly, is to create a stored procedure that can create a lock on a document and hold onto the lock for the lifetime of the stored procedure.

Comment: Yeah, not gonna happen :)

Comment: yeah, it appears that you are correct, that's a major deficiency in MongoDB, what a PoS :)  I need a locking mechanism.

Comment: Ok Sergio, you can do it like so (with TTL indexes) : https://speakerdeck.com/raindev/distributed-locking-with-mongodb

Comment: But it's a shitty mechanism, because you need to retry/poll to acquire the lock. But it will work if you really need it.

Comment: So I am just going to say it: you were wrong! :)

Comment: I wrote this, if you are interested - https://github.com/ORESoftware/live-mutex

Comment: I might end up using it, instead of TTL indexes in MongoDB, we will see.

Comment: That's application level lock. Any client is free to ignore it and update the collection at will. It's useless :)

Comment: That is correct, but all I need is an application level lock. I can walk into the server room and smash the hardware with a baseball bat if I want to. Of course, some rules need to be followed.

Comment: My guess is there are many more cases of needed an application level lock than a database level lock, no? I can't think of a need for a database level lock.

Comment: In a real ACID db, you don't have to agree to follow the rules. The rules are _enforced_ by the database. Just saying. :) If this works for you, then great, my job here is done :)

Comment: Well, if I had my way we would be using an RDBMS instead of MongoDB but it was not my call, thanks for your help in any case

Comment: @sergio if you add an answer basically summarizing what you said here, I will upvote, will probably help someone else at some point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*summarizing the comments above*)

At the moment, there is nothing in mongodb that will allow you to run a piece of arbitrary logic (including, for example, multiple queries to gather data) atomically.

The best atomic thing that mongodb has to offer is [findAndModify](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/). Its atomicity is naturally restricted to only one document and you have a pretty limited list of [update operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/#id1) (that is, you can't even use the fields of the document, same as regular updates).

It is *somewhat* possible using an application-level lock: the application inserts or modifies a special lock document, which will signal to other parts of the application "I'm using/updating this, please refrain from touching it". After the operation is completed, application releases the lock, so it's now free to be re-acquired by someone else. Of course, this relies *entirely* on actors respecting the lock agreements, which is not very reliable, to put it mildly.

Comment: TTL indexes "work" for locking with MongoDB but I don't know how well they really work

Comment: @AlexanderMills: TTL index (in the slide deck you reference) is only there to ensure lock release if, for whatever reason, your program crashes before it can release the lock normally. Other than this, they don't have anything to do with locking, whatsoever.

Comment: No not true, the lock holder acquires the lock by setting the index with ttl, when the lockholder is done, the lockholder deletes the index, system  does not have to wait til index expiry..the other lock requestors using polling to acquire the lock, they acauire the lock when they successfully create the index, when they are done they delete it. ttl is simply the critical feature needed if application goes down. Its a crappy locking system because it requires lots of polling but it will work.

Comment: @AlexanderMills: what do you mean "they create the index"? No indexes are dynamically created/deleted at runtime in that scenario, I assure you. :)

Comment: drop index, https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.dropIndex/

Comment: it's the TTL that is the important feature, like I said

Comment: so you you use a collection called Locks, you can add as many indexes as you want and drop as many as you want. you can create indexes dynamically :)

Comment: @AlexanderMills: yes, you can, in theory. Yet in that scenario (from the slide deck) you do not add/remove any indexes. You create the TTL index one time and then you never touch it again.

Comment: @AlexanderMills: do you, perhaps, think that a TTL index is an index that self-destructs after its timeout runs out?

Comment: sorry I was trying to remember an implementation  - it's not that we are creating/dropping indexes willy nilly, we are creating / deleting documents which represent locks, and the ttl index guarantees that it will eventually get deleted.

Comment: @AlexanderMills: yep, with that I can agree.